# Fixed menu at top but not the first element

Tags: css, menu

How can i use position: fixed; for my menu, when it isn't the first element on the website.
My logo is the top item on the website, thereafter the menu. When i scroll down the page i want the menu to be the top element. How can i do this? And is it possible with only css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would require the use of javaScript, but can be done quite simply.

**Example**

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QekDr/)

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <p class="site-title">
        <a href="#">Your logo here</a>
    </p>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
ul{
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0;
}

ul li{
    display: inline;
}

.fixed{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function ()
    {
        // Get the initial position of the menu.
        var menuTop = $('nav').offset().top;

        $(window).scroll(function ()
        {
            // Check position
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > menuTop)
            {
                $('nav').addClass('fixed');
            }
            else
            {
                $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick respond. I have tried the solution however i can't seem to make it work. The code is imported alright and i have tried to disable all the existing javascript codes for the menu, but it still doesn't work. Do you have any clue whats wrong? (i know it's hard when you don't know all the facts, but if you have an idea of what the problem could be i would be very grateful

Comment: Can you post your code as a JsFiddle and then I can have a look for you.

Comment: Hi, I have build it on the free framework "T3" from joomlart for the Joomla cms system.